# How would I compare the letter to my word in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a hangman game and I need to compare the letter chosen (working in the code below) to the word and then replace the underscore of the letter with the letter if correct, how exactly would I go about doing this?

Sorry in advance, I'm not very good at this and a high school student.

```css
/* Hangman Game CSS File */
body
{
 background-color: #1B264F;
}

#main {
 background-color: #5386E4;
 height: 97vh; 
    width: 95vw;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
canvas {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Hangman by Lachlan Teale</title> 
  <meta name="description" content="Lachlan Teale's Hangman Game 2015">
  <meta name="keywords" content="hangman, lachlan, teale, Javascript">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="author" content="Lachlan Teale">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <canvas id="main" width="1920" height="1080" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 //setting variables
  var canvas = document.getElementById('main');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
       var underscore = "";
       var letter;
       var complete = false;

 //list of words
  var wordList = ["apple", "peach", "pear", "mango", "banana", "paper", "pens", "laptop", "desk", "chair", "star", "sky", "moon", "sun", "planets"];

 //picking a random word from the list
  var word = wordList[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordList.length)];

 //print out the underscores for the number of letters
  for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
   var underscore = underscore + "_ ";
  }

  context.font = '50pt Calibri';
       context.textAlign = 'center';
       context.fillStyle = '#E2E2E3';
       context.fillText(underscore, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.70);

    //correct letter text
       context.font = 'bold 30pt Calibri';
       context.textAlign = 'center';
       context.fillStyle = '#E2E2E3';
       context.text
       context.fillText("Correct Letters", canvas.width * 0.08, canvas.height * 0.05);

    //Wrong Letter text
       context.font = 'bold 30pt Calibri';
       context.textAlign = 'center';
       context.fillStyle = '#E2E2E3';
       context.text
       context.fillText("Wrong Letters", canvas.width - (canvas.width * 0.08), canvas.height * 0.05);

 //checking which button is pressed
  window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
   if ( event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90 ) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);  
          letter = String.fromCharCode( event.keyCode ).toLowerCase();
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = '#E2E2E3';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
        }
  });

  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {                     
      if ( event.keyCode == 8 ) {              
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
      }
     });

       document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {                     
      if( event.keyCode == 13 ) {
       alert(letter + " and enter was pressed");
      }
     });
  
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's nice to provide a full example, but also nice to show which part of your code is relevant to your question. What you're asking for is pretty simple. One word: `indexOf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use indexOf to detect the presence of the letter:

```
word.indexOf(letter);
```

Use replace to replace `_`:

```
underscore = underscore.replace(/_/g, function(m, index) {
    return word[index] === letter ? letter : m;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2y4so8t0/

Comment: how exactly would I edit the javascript to print it in a html5 canvas?

Comment: Clear the zone where you put the underscore string, and write it again using ``fillText``. You should probably use a monospace font (see my jsfiddle) so that each letter takes the same amount of space.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method match() with regular expression to check for matching words in a string

```
var str = "The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain"; 
var res = str.match(/ain/g);
```